# K-theory of finite diagram categories

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, algebraic-k-theory

Suppose $I$ is a finite $\infty$-category and $F:I\rightarrow\text{fCW}$ is a functor that takes values in finite CW complexes. For each $X\in I$, let $[F(X)]$ denote the class of $F(X)$ in $K_0(\text{fCW})\cong\mathbb{Z}$.

Since evaluation at $X$ is a right exact functor, $[F(-)]$ is a homomorphism $K_0(\text{fCW}^I)\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$. As we let $X$ vary over equivalence classes of objects in $I$, these assemble into a homomorphism $$K_0(\text{fCW}^I)\xrightarrow{ev}\bigoplus_{X\in I/\cong}\mathbb{Z}.$$ **Question**: Is this an isomorphism?

**Remark**: There is a splitting like this one when fCW is replaced by abelian/stable categories. See for example https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3417

**Edit**: Tom Goodwillie points out this is not the isomorphism one would expect, but I am still curious whether $K_0(\text{fCW}^I)$ splits according to the objects of $I$ (and maybe their automorphism groups, as in the paper linked above), or whether it can be computed at all in general.

K-theory can mean so many things, I want to be clear: When I write $K_0(\mathcal{C})$, I mean the abelian group supporting a universal function $[-]:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow K_0(\mathcal{C})$ such that:

- if $X\cong Y$, then $[X]=[Y]$,
- $[X\amalg Y]=[X]+[Y]$,
- if $A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C$ is a cofiber sequence, $[B]=[A]+[C]$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your definitions, but it seems that if $I$ is an ordinary category then the left hand side is invariant under equivalence of categories while the right hand side depends on the object set.

Comment: You're right! I meant to sum over each equivalence class of $X\in I$. I will correct that.

Comment: If you take $I$ to be the standard simplicial circle then I think the functor category has infinitely many isomorphism classes. However the indexing simplicial set is not a quasi-category, so this is maybe not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If $I = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ counts as a finite $\infty$ category (Edit: it doesn't), then the answer is no.  The space $* \sqcup *$  admits both a free and a trivial $I$ action.  We have an additive map given by taking homology and pairing with the alternating representation $$X \mapsto \chi(H^*(X, \mathbb C), {\rm alt}) = \sum_{i} (-1)^i \dim (H^i(X, \mathbb C) \otimes{ \rm alt})^{\mathbb Z/2}$$  which distinguishes between the two actions on $* \sqcup *$.

Comment: It's a finite category, but not a finite $\infty$-category, because the nerve $\mathbb{R}P^\infty=B\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is not a finite cell complex.

If you want to think about ordinary categories, I am interested in categories like finite posets, or groups like $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, or $\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$. (Finiteness is rather different for categories and $\infty$-categories.)

Comment: OK thanks, I thought finite might mean postnikov finite instead of CW finite.

Comment: Even for $I=\mathbb Z$ the answer is no. A diagram is a finite complex $X$ with automorphism $a:X\to X$, right? And there are at least two independent maps from the $K$-group to $\mathbb Z$, the Euler characterisitc of $X$ and the Lefschetz number of $a$.

Comment: Great, I think this right. I also think answer would change if we took the K theory of finitely generated  (i.e. compact) $I$ spaces.

Comment: Yes, you're right... I was being too naive. But I am still curious if there is some form of splitting like in the paper I referenced. The terms would not be Z, but K_0 of something coming from the automorphism groups in I.

Comment: I don't think $B\mathbb Z$ is a finite ∞-category either, but $B\mathbb N$ is.

Comment: @MarcHoyois $B\Bbb Z$ turns out to be finite. There's a presentation of $B\Bbb Z$ with one object, three morphisms $l, f, r$, and two homotopies $lf = id$, $fr = id$. (If you demand that the left inverse and right inverse are equal then you get the wrong answer and have to add higher cells; this is related to $B\Bbb Z$ not having a finite $C_2$-equivariant description)

Comment: @TylerLawson Ah yes, my mistake. Thanks for the correction!